# How to get all Event name on dayClick in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, cakephp, fullcalendar

in Fullcalendar i want to get event name on dayClick: function.

> selectable: true,
>
> selectHelper: true,
>
> dayClick: function(calEvent,date,allDay,jsEvent,view) {
>
> > alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
> >
> > }

its working on eventClick

> > eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
> >           alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);  }

but i want it on dayclick 
[image: sample]

Comment: Failed formatting (this is fixed now); non-existent description; if you want usage help, this is offtopic; if you want us to debug your app, we can't, you haven't shown code (this is semi-fixed now as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), the [dayClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) event handler gets four parameters:

```
date, allDay, jsEvent, view
```

You are expecting an extra parameter at the beginning:

```
calEvent, date, allDay, jsEvent, view
```

Then with

```
alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
```

you are accessing the date title (which there turns out to be none).

The parameter you want seems to not be supplied by the fullCalendar plugin (perhaps because there was no event clicked whose title you might be interested in?)

There seems to be no relevant method in the Date object, but you could fetch all events and filter them: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/

Comment: any method for getting whole event title or return true if there is any event on day click ????

Comment: @YogeshSaroya you need to fetch the list of events for that day. Do you want me to do some digging in the API documentation?

Comment: @JanDvorak i need to check if there are any events on a day click, but don't understand what you have explained above here.